# Why binding a function to null context?

Tags: javascript, this

I am working with the following functions atm, but what confused me is why in function `request`, we need to bind `sendRequest` to `null` by doing `sendRequest.apply(null, _arguments))`?

In `sendRequest` definition, there is no `this` in it, does it not make its context binding meaningless?

```
function sendRequest(args = {}) {
    args.data = _param(args.data);
    args.method = args.method || 'GET';
    args.error = isFunction(args.error) ? args.error : function () {};
    args.success = isFunction(args.success) ? args.success : function () {};
    args.parseResponse = args.hasOwnProperty('parseResponse') ? args.parseResponse : true;

    const myXhr = new PostMessageProxyRequest();

    if (args.method === 'GET') {
        let queryString = '?';

        if (args.url.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
            queryString += '&';
        }
        args.url += queryString + args.data;
    }
    myXhr.open(args.method, baseUrl + args.url);
    if (args.headers) {
        for (const key in args.headers) {
            if (args.headers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                myXhr.setRequestHeader(key, args.headers[key]);
            }
        }
    }
    myXhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', CONTENT_TYPE.FORM);

    function callError(status, response) {
        if (args.parseResponse) {
            try {
                response = JSON.parse(response);
            } catch (e) {} // eslint-disable-line no-empty
        }
        args.error.call(null, { status, response });
    }

    myXhr.onload = function () {
        let content = myXhr.responseText;

        if (myXhr.status >= 200 && myXhr.status <= 300) {
            try {
                if (content && content.length > 0 && args.parseResponse) {
                    content = JSON.parse(content);
                }
                try {
                    args.success.call(null, {
                        status: myXhr.status,
                        response: content
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    callError(-1, `${e.name} on success handler, msg: ${e.message}`);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                callError(-1, `error parsing response: ${e.message}. Response: ${content}`);
            }
        } else {
            callError(myXhr.status, content);
        }
    };
    myXhr.onerror = function () {
        callError(myXhr.status, myXhr.responseText);
    };
    myXhr.send(args.method === 'POST' || args.method === 'PUT' ? args.data : null);
}

function request(args = {}) {
    const _arguments = arguments;

    args.error = args.error || (() => {});

    init()
        .then(() => sendRequest.apply(null, _arguments))
        .catch((options = {}) => args.error.call(null, options));
}
```

Comment: The `.apply` call has nothing to do with the `this` context in this case which is why whoever wrote it set it to `null`, the point is to spread the array `_arguments` into positional arguments in the function call. In fact, that looks like tool-generated code more than hand-written, the original was probably something like `sendRequest(...arguments)`

Comment: i see, this legacy code was probably written pre-ES6 era

Comment: Or more likely it was written more currently and then compiled to run on older browsers.